Twisted Looping Call and While True
I am trying to combine two bits of code. The first is a simple Twisted looping call that runs once per minute. A simple scheduler type setup.
def minuteCheck():
    # Do some stuff once a minute like triggering an event based on the hour and minute

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # once a minute
    lc_min = LoopingCall(minuteCheck)
    lc_min.start(60)

    # go!
    logger.debug("Starting Twisted")
    reactor.run()


the second bit of code is a code to run a screen and buttons from Pimoroni. The code is based around a try, while True and except.
https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/unicorn-hat-mini
if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        button_a.when_pressed = pressed
        button_b.when_pressed = pressed
        button_x.when_pressed = pressed
        button_y.when_pressed = pressed

        while True:

            # Code here that draws items to the pixel screen

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        button_a.close()
        button_b.close()
        button_x.close()
        button_y.close()


It seems to be that the While True part of the code above is blocking the code and stopping the loopingCall from working.
How do I integrate these two bits of code into each other?

Can you use multithreading?

Sounds like a good option, but I don't know anything about that at present.

Only the __main__ of unicornhat has a "while True" loop in it.  And all that loop does is 5 or 6 lines of logic and then sleep for a while.  Keep the 5 or 6 lines of logic, throw out the "while True" and the "sleep" in favor of ... another LoopingCall!
